# invoke virtual method on null object reference (setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled)

Tags: java

I want my update_activity to display a back arrow button but this code gives me this error:

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
> ```

at this line:

> ```
> getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
> ```

What do you suggest?

```
public class UpdateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;
AppBarLayout appbar;

private static Socket s;
private static PrintWriter pw;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.UpdateButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            connect();
        }
    });

}
```

when I substitute that command with

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

it returns me this other error (which I think is the same):

Unable to start activity

`ComponentInfo{io.anycopy.googleplusdemo/io.anycopy.googleplusdemo.UpdateActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Well it sounds like `getSupportActionBar()` is returning null - so that's what you need to investigate. Does the documentation for that method mention circumstances in which it would return null?

Comment: What theme are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using NoActionBar themes, in which case getSupportActionBar () return null and you must either change the theme or use getActionBar ()